# Specify ignore custom file patterns in .ackrc

Tags: ack

I have certain CSS files of fileName *-c.css and *-gen.css which I want to ignore from ack-grep searches.

I see that *--type-set=TYPENAME=.extension* does not accept regex filters like **-c.css*, any idea of how to get around this problem ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I came across ack-grep 2.0 which provides *--ignore-file* option based on regex pattern as below and it worked after adding it to *~/.ackrc*.

```
--ignore-file=match:-c.js
--ignore-file=match:-gen.js
--ignore-file=match:-c.css
--ignore-file=match:-gen.css
```

Comment: for exact file names:
`--ignore-file=is:<filename>` - for ctags file: `--ignore-file=is:tags`

Comment: Filters for different uses can be found on http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.10-man.html#defining_your_own_types

Comment: For all the too-fast readers finding this: Note that the '-' in the match string above is not saying "remove c.js files" - the '-' is part of the file name in the original question!

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to filter those files you want to search.

```
ack -G '(?<!-c)(?<!-gen)\.css$' expression_to_search
```

It uses the `perl` flavour. I do a negative look-behind to skip those that contain `-c` or `-gen` just before the extension.

Comment: For those reading this in 2019 or beyond, ack 3.x doesn't support the `-G` option.  You have to use `ack -g pattern | ack -x expression_to_search`.